# Can't get character encoding to work from android client with resttemplate and json

Tags: android, json, character-encoding, httpclient, resttemplate

Ok, so ive tried everything but asking at stackoverflow...

I'm trying to perform a REST call with some http params from an Android using httpclient and resttemplate to a server-side Spring controller. All my Swedish chars end up on the server as '\u001A'...

setting up httpclient and resttemplate code:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

Credentials defaultcreds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(msisdn, password);
httpClient.getState().setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT, AuthScope.ANY_REALM), defaultcreds);

//httpClient.getParams().setContentCharset(prefs.());
httpClient.getParams().setCredentialCharset(prefs.getCredentialsEncoding());

CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);

// Add message converters
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> mc = restTemplate.getMessageConverters();
MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter json = new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter();

List<MediaType> supportedMediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
json.setSupportedMediaTypes(supportedMediaTypes);
mc.add(json);
restTemplate.setMessageConverters(mc);

return restTemplate;
```

I then prepare a httpentity with my parameter:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
headers.add("myparam", "" + "å");
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
```

I finally make the rest call:

```
ResponseEntity<UserStatusTO> response = rest.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity,
            MyResponseClass.class);
```

On the server, i have a jackson deserializer and my spring controller method looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/event/out", headers = "Accept=application/json", produces = {"application/xml;charset=UTF-8", "application/json;charset=UTF-8"})
public
@ResponseBody
UserStatusTO out(Authentication auth, @RequestHeader(value="myparam", required =  false) String myparam) {
```

All the special chars end up as \u001a ! I've tried tons of stuff, re-encoding the strings manually client AND server side, none worked. I've tried fiddling with the 
    httpClient.getParams().setContentCharset();
    httpClient.getParams().setUriCharset();

None worked as far as i could tell.

I'm out of ideas! If anybody has any input, i'd be much obliged. Thanks!

Comment: Except for the "myparam" header, where are you cramming in the å, ä:s and ö:s?

Comment: Well, there's only one parameter that has swedish characters. I shortened my example to get make it easier to read, but in my app there's a field where the user can enter a note that i'm trying to send to the server... But the place where i have the "å" is where i in my code put in the text from the textfield

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue and I fixed it by setting the proper content-type AND character set manually instead of using MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
Charset utf8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
MediaType mediaType = new MediaType("application", "json", utf8);
headers.setContentType(mediaType);
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an issue on the server side since the Apache HTTP client will gladly output Latin-1 characters in headers, as you can test with this simple test:

```
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://www.riksdagen.se");
get.addHeader("SwedishHeader", "Mona Sahlin är ett nötdjur");

ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
SessionOutputBufferImpl buffer = new SessionOutputBufferImpl(out, get.getParams());
HttpRequestWriter writer = new HttpRequestWriter(buffer, BasicLineFormatter.DEFAULT, get.getParams());

writer.write(get);
buffer.flush();
System.out.println(out.toString("ISO-8859-1"));
```

SessionOutputBufferImpl is a little hack to use the AbstractSessionOutputBuffer

```
class SessionOutputBufferImpl extends AbstractSessionOutputBuffer {
    SessionOutputBufferImpl(OutputStream out, HttpParams params) {
        init(out, 1024, params);
    }
}
```

You should probably concentrate on your server backend - what are you using? If it's "fixed" - you should consider trying to format your header according to [RFC 2407](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt) - some servers support, others fail miserably.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i can confirm that it's not the server. I spent the day updating my IOS application with the same functionality and the texts arrive fine, encoded properly and all characters look ok in the database where they end up...

Comment: Have you wiresharked your server input & checked for encoding differences?